# Editing on external file Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have some data displayed on a grid generated with JQgrid. I want to do the edit of a selected row on a separate PHP file. What I need is that when I click a row on the Jqgrid, I got an ID for the selected row, and send it as a parameter to that separate PHP file, which is called by pressing a button that is not part of the grid, also warn the user if he press the edit button and no row is selected on the JQGrid. Somebody know how to do this?

Below is the code of the JQgrid table that I'm creating for the JQGrid, with the button to redirect to the other file:

```
        <div>
           <h1>Manejo de alumnos</h1>
           <table id="list"></table><!--Grid table-->
           <div id="pager"></div>  <!--pagination div-->
        </div>
    <br>    

    <a href="http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Alumnos_controller/editData" class="btn btn-primary">Editar alumno</a>
```

Here is the code of my JQgrid:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Alumnos_controller/loadData',
            mtype : "post",             //Ajax request type. It also could be GET
            datatype: "json",            //supported formats XML, JSON or Arrray
            colNames:['Expediente','Primer apellido','Segundo apellido', 'Nombre','Cédula'],       //Grid column headings
            colModel:[
                {name:'expediente',index:'expediente', width:300, editable:true, edittype:'text'},
                {name:'primerApellido',index:'primerApellido', width:300, editable:true, edittype:'text'},
                {name:'segundoApellido',index:'segundoApellido', width:300, editable:true, edittype:'text'},
                {name:'nombre',index:'nombre', width:300, editable:true, edittype:'text'},
                {name:'cedula',index:'cedula', width:300, editable:true, edittype:'text'}

            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[15,30],
            sortname: 'primerApellido',
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
    postData: {expediente:"expediente"},
            caption: 'Alumnos'
        }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:true},
            {//EDITAR
                url:"http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Alumnos_controller/deleteData"
            },
            {
                //AGREGAR
              },
              {// DELETE
                jqModal:false,
                reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                savekey: [true,13],
                drag: true,
                closeOnEscape:true,
                closeAfterAdd:true,
                url:"http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Alumnos_controller/deleteData",
                onclickSubmit:function(params, postdata){
                    var index=$("#list").getGridParam("selrow");                            
        var rowId = jQuery('#list tr:eq('+index+')').attr('ID');
        var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
        var dataFromCellByColumnName = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'expediente');
        return { expediente: dataFromCellByColumnName };

                }

    },  

            {multipleSearch : false}, // enable the advanced searching
    {closeOnEscape:true} /* allow the view dialog to be closed when user press ESC key*/

        );
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I was able to work on this again until today. See my reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up an event every time a row is selected where you pass the information to your Edit Button via:

```
 onSelectRow: function(id){
   //pass id to button
```

and then you can test when the edit button is pressed if a row is selected by

```
if ($('#gridName').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')) {
...
}
else {
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I have to pass to the button? where should I put that onSelectRow function?

Comment: @Vito This would go in your jqGrid setup on the client side, you can send whatever you need to send to uniquely identify the record you selected so you can use your button as you set out above.

Comment: I just set everything, I extracted the field that I need to send as parameter from my grid, and I have the button now detecting if a row is selected or not thanks to your code. Now to finish, how can I pass that parameter to the button?

Comment: I just find out how to do it, thanks a lot for your help. I will post another answer explaining in detail what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using Mark's answer and doing some investigation. First, you need to pass some parameter which is going to be used by the button, this parameter will depend on the logic of your grid. The code to get the parameter is the following, you need to place this in the section which contain the ColModel:

```
                onSelectRow: function(id)
            {
                var dataFromCellByColumnName="";
                var index=$("#list").getGridParam("selrow");
                var rowId = jQuery('#list tr:eq('+index+')').attr('ID');
                var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                dataFromCellByColumnName = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'expediente');
                setExpediente(dataFromCellByColumnName);

            }
```

On this particular case, I'm sending the "expediente" field of the grid to the "setExpediente" function. The setExpediente function is:

```
        var expediente="";
        function setExpediente(elExpediente)
        {
            expediente = elExpediente;
        }
```

Note that the variable "expediente" is a global variable. Then, you need to create a function that will use the global variable "expediente". I made this one:

```
function revisarSeleccion()
        {
            if (expediente=="")
            {
                alert("Seleccione una fila")
            }
            else
            {
                alert(expediente);    
            }

        }
```

This will check if the variable "expediente" is blank or not, and depending on the results you can make your decisions.

Thanks to Mark for his help on this.

Comment: Isn't this what I put above? But more complicated? It just seems weird to take my answer to get what you need then post up your own and mark it as the answer...

Comment: Well, some points were not clear on your answer, like how to send the parameter to the button. My Idea was to have two answers, but I'm not sure if this is possible here. Anyway, I will mark your post as the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.